# How to establish a realtime communcation from a browser extension to qt

Tags: javascript, qt, firefox-addon

I'm working on a firefox extension which requires a real-time connectivity between the system side software and web.

I mean, I want something like this

**in extension**

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(childList){sendToQt(JSON.stringify(childList))})
observer.observe(myElement,{childList:true})
```

**in qt application.**

```
public signals:
    void messageReceived(QString message)

connect(myobject, &MyClass::messageReceived,this,&ThisClass::logMessage)
void logMessage(QString message){
    std::cout<<message.toStdString()<<endl;
    sendMessageBack(recieved)
}
```

When a mutation observed by mutation observer initialized with extension, it has to be send to qt as a string message and response from qt to extension. I am much familiar with python sockets. But it seems that it's not gonna work with such a project. Basically it's by first firefox extension build and I am not much familiar with facilities provided by firefox for an extension. Is there any such technology which establishes a real-time communication between qt and my extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy IPC using what both Qt and Browser extensions support:

- **Websockets**: Simple, bidirectional, you can pass JSON around
- **A local HTTP/S API**: A bit more fancy and structured, possibly more cumbersome if you just want local IPC

### WebSocket

1. **Qt**: Create a [`QWebSocketServer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocketserver.html) in your Qt application, and connect to the usual signal. See [Qt WebSocket example from the "Echo Server"](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebsockets.git/tree/examples/websockets/echoserver/echoserver.cpp?h=5.15) for an actual example.
2. **Qt**: Use [`QJson`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html) for encoding and decoding
3. **Firefox extension**: Create a `new WebSocket(<url>)` in your Firefox extension, and connect to `locahost` on the port/path you defined in your Qt app. Here is a [Sample extension using WebSockets for Firefox](https://github.com/WangFenjin/Simple-WebSocket-Client)
4. Communicate happily between the two!

### HTTP/S API

You get the idea, in this case you use third party library like [Mangoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose), [RESTinio](https://github.com/Stiffstream/restinio), or [CppRestSDK](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk).

A couple open source Qt alternatives exist as well for convenience, but will likely the maturity of other projects. And the Qt official HTTP server isn't in the mainline Qt 5 versions AFAIK.